# How can I find and print unmatched/dissimilar words from the documents?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, gensim

I am trying to rewrite algorithm that basically takes a input text file and compares with different documents and results the similarities.

Now I want to print output of unmatched words and output a new textile with unmatched words.

From this code, "hello force" is the input and is checked against the raw_documents and prints out rank for matched document between 0-1(word "force" is matched with second document and ouput gives more rank to second document but "hello" is not in any raw_document i want to print unmatched word "hello" as not matched ), But what i want is to print unmatched input word that was not matched with any of the raw_document

```
import gensim
import nltk

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

raw_documents = ["I'm taking the show on the road",
                 "My socks are a force multiplier.",
             "I am the barber who cuts everyone's hair who doesn't 
cut their own.",
             "Legend has it that the mind is a mad monkey.",
            "I make my own fun."]

gen_docs = [[w.lower() for w in word_tokenize(text)]
            for text in raw_documents]

dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(gen_docs)

corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(gen_doc) for gen_doc in gen_docs]

tf_idf = gensim.models.TfidfModel(corpus)
s = 0
for i in corpus:
    s += len(i)
sims =gensim.similarities.Similarity('/usr/workdir/',tf_idf[corpus],
                                  num_features=len(dictionary))
query_doc = [w.lower() for w in word_tokenize("hello force")]

query_doc_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(query_doc)

query_doc_tf_idf = tf_idf[query_doc_bow]
result = sims[query_doc_tf_idf] 
print result
```

Comment: It's not yet clear what you want to do, and why. You may want to edit your qeustions to clarify: Are your documents real natural-language text? Do you want your "word matching" to help determine if a text is similar to other known texts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to know that the word '`hello'` is not in a some other documents, that may not even require a natural-language helper library like `gensim`. You could insead just keep a record of all seen words – and for that a plain Python `dict` or `set` or `Counter` should be sufficient. (After loading it with all words, just check each word of your new text against it in turn.)

Gensim's `TfidfModel` and the `Similarity` comparisons actually. deals with more subtle relative-degrees-of-comparison (not the "yes/no" of a word's presence).

And, the `gensim.corpora.Dictionary.doc2bow()` method will usually *ignore* unknown-to-the-Dictionary words – because they don't have assigned slots, and are thus perhaps rare/unimportant – rather than include them in the returned data. So, the "bag of words" representations it returns by default, which are essentially lists of `(known_word_index, count)` can't help for simple not-yet-seen detection of not-yet-known words.

However, you could look at its optional `return_missing` parameter, and request `return_missing=True`. Then, it returns a tuple of (bag_of_words, dict_of_missing_words) - and by looking at that second returned value, see which words *weren't* already in the `gensim.corpora.Dictionary` object. See:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html#gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary.doc2bow